# How to drop a query in a url?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have the following url: `http://0.0.0.0:3000/book/all?my_query`.

How can I drop the `all?my_query` and leave just `book/`?

I tried to do something like this:

```js
if (this.$route.params.item === 'all') { 
  this.$router.replace ('/') 
}
```

But that approach just returns me to the main page.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To remove all params:

```
this.$router.replace({'query': null});
```

To add `my_query` param:

```
this.$router.replace({'query': {'my_query': 1}});
```

Comment: And how do I just delete `my_query` instead of all queries? `this.$router.replace({'query.my_query': null});` throws syntax error.

Comment: A bit too late to the party BUT `router.replace({'query.my_query': null});` shouldn't throw a syntax error. Make sure that you don't have a typo elsewhere on that line.

Comment: For me, it was `this.$router.replace({ query: undefined });` which worked

Answer (score 6):

here is the solution:

```js
$router.push($route.path)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation

Answer (score 1):

Add this inside your callback

```
this.$router.replace({'query': null});
```

It will clear you router query and stay same page without refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to drop one or some *but not all* query parameters, then just spread the existing parameters into an object and overwrite the one(s) you don't want anymore with `undefined`:

```js
let newQueryParams = {
   ...this.$route.query,
   paramToClear: undefined,
};

this.$router.replace({ query: newQueryParams });

// Before: www.example.com/?page=3&paramToClear=15
// After: www.example.com/?page=3
```

Using `null` instead of `undefined` may clear the parameter's *value*, but in my experimentation the parameter was left in the URL as an "empty" parameter, e.g.:
`www.example.com/?page=12` became `www.example.com/?page`.

Also note that while this won't trigger a page refresh, it still counts as a navigation change, which **will likely trigger the components on your page to reinitialize & rerender**.

Answer (score -5):

simply delete query object's property

```
    delete this.$route.query.my_query
```